# Font conditional style CSS

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, typekit, left-to-right

I have a website that uses one Latin and one Arabic font (Adobe Typekit fonts).

The **dynamically generated text** (p) is in Italics and sometimes is written in Latin and sometimes in Arabic.

So I have a CSS rule:

```
p {
   font-family: "Arno-Pro", "Athelas-Arabic", serif;
   font-style: italic; 
}
```

The problem is that the Arabic font does not have italic characters, as Arabic is a language that is written with font-style: normal; so instead of using the Arabic font, it falls back to ugly system font.

For demonstration purposes to make it simpler, imagine that I have this line of text:

```
<p> Lorem ipsum لكن لا بد </p>
```

How can I target the Latin letters to be loaded as italics and the arabic letters to be loaded normal?

**Note:** The text is generated dynamically and cannot use custom markup within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the actually used fonts via `@font-face` rules with specific [unicode ranges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range):

```css
p {
   font-family: "Arno-Pro", serif;
   font-style: italic; 
}

/* default latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arno-Pro";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/notosans/v27/o-0OIpQlx3QUlC5A4PNr4ARCQ_k.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-style: italic;
}

/* override for arabic unicode range */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arno-Pro";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/notosansarabic/v18/nwpxtLGrOAZMl5nJ_wfgRg3DrWFZWsnVBJ_sS6tlqHHFlhQ5l3sQWIHPqzCfyGyfuXqA.woff2) format('woff2');
  /* arabic unicode range */
  unicode-range: U+0600-06FF;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<p class="mixed">Lorem ipsum لكن لا بد latin text again</p>
```

In the above example we're specifying a css override for the previously declared default font mapping:

- the default font should be "Arno Pro"
- characters within the unicode range of the Arabic alphabet (in this case: U+0600-06FF) should be mapped to another font file (supporting these characters or more precisely glyphs)
- and also be mapped to `font-style:italic` – otherwise text would be artificially slanted (also called ["faux italic"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/avoiding-faux-weights-styles-google-web-fonts/)).

So instead of specifying a dedicated arabic font in the `font-family` property, we override the font mapping like this:

```
p {
   font-family: "Arno-Pro", serif;
   font-style: italic; 
}

/* override for arabic unicode range */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arno-Pro";
  src: url(fonts/Athelas-Arabic.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0600-06FF;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

This css rule translates to:
For this (arabic) unicode range – take the "Athelas-Arabic" font files (so this becomes the "Arno-Pro").
By adding a `font-style:italic` property, we circumvent a "faux-italic" slanting, since our css rule says: this is already a proprer italic font (even it's not).

Comment: Just to add that because I'm using Adobe fonts, the fonts are loaded from a URL in this format: https://use.typekit.net/xxxxxxx.css So, I had to open this URL using the browser and copied the CSS @font-face of the "Athelas-Arabic" font. Then I added it manually on my site, by modifying the font-style: normal; to font-style: italic; It worked perfectly. Beautiful solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <div>
          <h2>Latin text</h2>      
          <h3 class="ar">لكن لا بد أن أوضح لك أن كل<h3>
        </div>   
    
          <style>
                h2, h3 {
        font-family: Latin, Arabic, serif;
        font-style: Italic;
        }
                 .ar{
                  font-style: normal; !important
                }
              </style>
```

is this what you  are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you must add the "!important" to your font style 
 
h2, h3 { 
font-family: Latin, Arabic, serif; 
font-style: Italic !important; 
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).