# How to change font-family for particular language automatically using concepts of ASCII Code Charecters?

Tags: html, css, font-family

I'm Using two languages on my website that is English and Marathi, sometimes I use mix combination of Marathi and English in a single line so I can't divide them using any class or ID each time
Eg.HTML CSS किंवा Javascript,PHP वापरून भाषा कशी बदलायची?
I read one solution like

```
@font-face {   
    font-family: BBCBengali;
    src: url(fonts/BBCBengali.ttf) format("opentype");
    unicode-range: U+00-FF, U+980-9FF;
}
```

```
So I want automatic if-else(without any selector) like 
If(Unicode range for English)
{
font-family: First-font;
}
Else
{
font-family: Second Font;
}
```

Comment: Did you understand that solution using `unicode-range`…? That basically is your “if-else” condition.

Comment: See also ["Font conditional style CSS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738758/font-conditional-style-css/73751094#73751094)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update :
This Problem is Solved with
Font-family: English Font, Non-English Font

But This will not solve the issue if both languages are in the same scripts